# import unique elements out of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, javascript

I've `ArrayList` (get_unique) of type integer where in I have to insert only unique values in
it. how can I do it??

I've got it some idea to do the same in javascript but do not know how to do it in Java?

```
 <%
ArrayList<Integer> get_unique = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> set_unique = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// how do it 
%>
```

---

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
// note: you will need to populate the myList() array with values!
var myList = new Array(); 
var uniqueList = new Array();
var uniqueListIndex = 0;

for (i=0;i<myList.length;i++) {
    var temp = myList[i];
    var unique = true;
    for (j=0;j<uniqueList.length;j++) {
        if (temp == uniqueList[j]) {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (unique == true) {
        uniqueList[uniqueListIndex] = temp;
        uniqueListIndex++;
    } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`Set<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead.

```
Set<Integer> unique = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
```

Duplicate entries will be automatically merged with existing entries. Note that using the [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) implementation will also maintain the insertion order like as in an `ArrayList`, while a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) implementation wouldn't maintain the insertion order. If you'd prefer automagic sort of entries, then use the [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) implementation instead.

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorial - Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If possible try using a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) rather than an Array - Sets will only allow one copy of each integer. You can create an array from the Set if you really need one using the `toArray()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `java.util.Set<E>` may be more suited. It only accepts unique values http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use `java.util.Set` instead of `java.util.List`. `Set` keeps one object only once.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get unique elements out of a *List* in Java is to turn it into a Set:

```
public List<Integer> getUniqueElements(List<Integer> list)
{
    //convert to a set to remove duplicates
    Set<Integer> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);

    //convert to a list and return
    return new ArrayList<Integer>(set);   
}

List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
myList.add(2);

List<Integer> get_uniq = getUniqueElements(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to eliminate duplicates and preserve the order of the list:

```
Set<Integer> uniqueSet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(get_unique);
List<Integer> unique_list = new ArrayList(uniqueSet);
```

Answer (score -1):

As the other people stated a class implementing the Java Set interface would be more suitable.

However if the use of an ArrayList is a requirement you can use the methods `ArrayList<E>.Contains(Object elem)` to verify if an object is already included in your ArrayList. But note that items are getting searched with the use of the `Object.equals(Object o)` method.